# Do I need a visa for layover in Bangkok waiting for next flight to VTE?

Tags: visas, transit, luggage, bangkok

I bought 2 flight tickets separate (not connect to each other); one from Sacramento to Suvarnabhumi Airport, Bangkok(BKK) (layover for 8hours), the other one is from BKK to VTE (Laos).

I'm planning to wait or hangout at the airport.My question are:

1. Do I need to get a Thailand visa (because my tickets not connect to
   each other)
2. Do I need to claim my baggage and go through customs & a security check in order for me to go back in to the airport and wait for next day flight to VTE?

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: Which airlines? You’ll need to reclaim your baggage if you can’t check it through from Sacramento to Laos.

Comment: Putting on hold until comments clarified.